# Maximum layer size in BFS tree for partial grid

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given positive integers $n$ and $m$. We choose any [partial grid](http://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_1057.html) $G$ that is a subgraph of $n \times m$ [grid](http://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_464.html). We choose some vertex $v$ of $G$ and run breadth first search (BFS) algorithm from this vertex. *Layer of BFS tree* is a set of vertices with the same distance (in edges) to $v$. The question is the following:

> What is the maximum size of layer of BFS tree over all choices of $G$ and $v$ for given $n$ and $m$?

Particularly, is it true that size of each layer is $O(n + m)$? Or can it be $\Omega(nm)$?

Background of this question is the following. I want to challenge student's solution for a problem that requires BFS on partial grid. The problem in his implementation is that he uses array instead of queue and deletes the first element shifting all others. Therefore time complexity of his implementation is $\Omega(\ell_0^2 + \ell_1^2 + \cdots + \ell_d^2)$, where $\ell_i$ is number of vertices with distance $i$ to vertex $v$ and $d$ is the maximum distance to $v$. This is obviously quadratically bad time for general case, however it would be acceptable by judge system subject to existing constraints on $n$ and $m$ (up to $300$) if there is no test case with layer size of $\omega(n + m)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a different example that has a leaf within each $2\times 2$ area:

[image: grid tree]

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: This is very nice construction! Maybe it is even the best possible for $m = n = 2^k - 1$. However it is still not enough in my case...

Comment: @Smylic What do you mean? It has $\Theta(n^2)$ leaves, as you wished. What else do you need for your tests?

Comment: I mean that I have already tried your idea and that solution has more than twice more time to run. That wasn't surprising due to a small constant under $\Theta$, that even squares further.

Comment: @Smylic Well, $n,m \leq 300$ are really small constants for these kind of tasks. BTW, just to be sure, are your time-limits adjusted (say, by timing the official solution) to the machine your are testing it on (like lab computer or a virtual machine on your own computer)?

Comment: You are right. But some of our problems are already 14 years old and came through 3 servers with different performance, so there is some confusion with constraints. However all essential changes are done between semesters only. Also raising constraints I take into account size of file which should be stored (multiple test cases) and read by each solution.

Comment: @Smylic I mean that you take the official solution (normally written, without any optimizations, no custom io, etc.) and set the limits to 3x-10x (depending on language and how tough you want to be) its running time. If the student passes, even with bad solution, he/she wins. Theoretical performance isn't everything (e.g. fast matrix multiplication).

Comment: we don't compare running time of two solutions, we have some time limit (an integral number of seconds) for each test and guarantee that every proper solution wouldn't break it. Surely there is a solution that gives this guarantee for each problem. Also I should say that practical performance may significantly depend on test structure as in case we are dealing with.

Comment: @Smylic I'm suggesting how to set time limit that is somewhat accurate – just time the official solution and set the time-limit to that multiplied 3 or some other number. Of course you will need adjustments if you want a good time limit, but it works well as a first approximation (and if you get a different computer, the official solution will run faster/slower too, so the time limit scales as well). The problem statement for TAs (rather than students) could express the time limit it in terms of running time of the included official implementation rather than fixed number of seconds.

Comment: Be sure I know all these tricks as I've won ACM ICPC Bronze medal and prepare problems for subregional and some other contests (including well-known Petrozavosk training camp) for 9 years. And for this problem in academic course I'll just wait for summer and raise up constraints on $n$ and $m$, because now it is hard to overrun 1 second even with quadratic approach.

Comment: @Smylic Now, that I am assured you know all these tricks, I can sleep soundly $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if the following construction is the maximum possible, but it beats $O(m+n)$:

[image: grid graph]

In a $n \times n$ grid with $n = 2^{k+1}-1$, we take the union of all paths from the center that take:

- $2^{k-1}$ steps in one direction;
- $2^{k-2}$ steps in a direction different from the previous;
- $2^{k-3}$ steps in a direction different from the previous (but possibly equal to the first direction);
- And so on, until we take a single step in some direction.

This is a tree with $\Theta(3^k) = \Theta(n^{\log_2 3})$ leaves, which is definitely $\omega(n)$ and more than halfway to the desired $\Omega(n^2)$.

Comment: Shame on me, I had this construction in my mind, but didn't evaluate it for some reason. Thank you!

Comment: There is a lot of empty space inside, you can make a special elongated path with lots of turns to create leaves there too (in a same fractal manner to what you already did.